# Setting a reference to a pointer to an object in a deque causes System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm new to C++ and I've had to implement a feature in an existing project. In order to do this, I had to create a dynamic collection of some sort, so initially went with a vector. After reading up on it, I thought a deque may be more fit for purpose.  In the main application, I declare a deque in the header.

```
std::deque<CSomeObject> SomeObjects;
```

The application has pools of threads which are started when threadmanager.GenerateAndProcessJobList() is called. threadmanager is initialized in the main application, and a reference to SomeObjects is passed into the constructor. When workers are created, a reference to the reference to SomeObjects is passed into the worker constructor. I have a function to find a specific object within the deque and insert it if it can’t be found. This is called from within the worker:

```
bool FindSomeObject(std::deque<CSomeObject> & SomeObjectVector,int ObjectID,CSomeObject *& ObjectRef){
    try{
        int CurrentObjectID;
        int vLength = SomeObjectVector.size();
        int i = 0;
        while(i < vLength){
            CSomeObject * cur = &SomeObjectVector[i];
            cur->GetIDs(CurrentObjectID);
            if(CurrentObjectID == ObjectID){
                ObjectRef = cur;    
                return true;
            }
            i++;
        }
        CSomeObject new_obj;
        new_obj.SetIDs(ObjectID);
        SomeObjectVector.push_back(new_obj);
        ObjectRef =  &SomeObjectVector.back();
        return true;
    }catch(std::exception& e){
        printf(e.what()); 
        return false;
    }
}
```

The application breaks with the exception, “System.AccessViolationException”. Looking at the call stack, the break occurred around the point FindSomeObject was called. I am aware that deque isn't thread safe. Other questions on StackOverflow imply that this kind of issue can be caused by multiple threads attempting to access the same object simultaneously or the initial object referenced being destroyed before its time. I'm certain that the object should still exist as it is in the scope of the main application and my watch shows me the objects that were successfully pushed onto it.

Any input on this, is, as always, greatly appreciated. If I were to push_back all necessary objects to SomeObjects from the main thread, would this help to address the issue at all?

Comment: Do not store the address of a `std::deque` or `std::vector` entry.  If either of those containers are resized, then that invalidates pointers and references to those items.

Comment: Basically, this is suspicious: `CSomeObject * cur = &SomeObjectVector[i];` and then `ObjectRef = cur;` (plus other similar lines).  Using a `std::vector` or `std::deque` leaves you vulnerable to iterator/pointer invalidation.  If iterators are invalidated, whatever `ObjectRef` was pointing to is also invalid.

Comment: Hi PaulMcKenzie, thanks for the input. Are there any collections in the standard containers library which I can use in this way and ill not invalidate my pointers/iterators? Also, if I changed my find function to be a function that modifies an object after moving it to the back of the deque, would this mean that it was safe to change params of the object at the back of the deque?

Comment: You can use a `std::list`, but remember you will not have random access iterators.  Or you can `reserve()` your vector size up front with the maximum number of entries (but this requires you to be sure of the max number of entries).